# How to implement GradCAM on a trained network - pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently working on my thesis and I am working with medical images. I want to add some GradCam visualisation on the outcome of my model. I am using a pretrained EfficientNet_b0 with ‘features_only=True’ (timm library):

```
class EfficientNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # base model
        self.feature_extractor = timm.create_model('efficientnet_b0', pretrained=True, features_only=True)
        # Get the number input features that the classifier receive. 
        # define the classifier. Note that the feature extractor keep 
        self.classification_label = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.feature_extractor.feature_info.channels()[-1], 1280),
            torch.nn.ReLU(True),
            torch.nn.Dropout(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1280, 1280),
            torch.nn.ReLU(True),
            torch.nn.Dropout(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1280, 4) # the labels are 4 
            )
        
        self.classification_reason = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.feature_extractor.feature_info.channels()[-1], 1280),
            torch.nn.ReLU(True),
            torch.nn.Dropout(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1280, 1280),
            torch.nn.ReLU(True),
            torch.nn.Dropout(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1280, 3) # the reasons are 3
            )
      
        
        self.flat_gap = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
            torch.nn.Flatten()
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        features = self.flat_gap(self.feature_extractor(x)[-1])
        label = self.classification_label(features)
        reason = self.classification_reason(features)
        
        return label, reason
```

My model gets the features of the last convolution layer and then forward passes them to two classifiers. One classifier for the diagnoses (labels) of the images and one classifier for the reasons for bad quality (bad_light, blurry, low_resolution) of the images.

After training my model, I want to load the saved weights and present a GradCam visualisation of the second classifier (for bad quality reasons). I want to get a heatmap representation for each reason. Can someone help me with the implementation?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try using this repo: https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam#using-from-code-as-a-library. What did go wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this repo, but the model is trained on ImageNet. I want to use my model weights, after its trained on my training set. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GradCAM implementation in this GitHub repo.
There are tutorials that you can follow to apply GradCAM on your own network. It's quite straightforward.
https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32528175)